# WebViewClient onLoadResource analog in WKWebView

Tags: android, ios, resources, wkwebview, webviewclient

I did saw the documentation of WebViewClient of android and examine method <onLoadResources - Notify the host application that the WebView will load the resource specified by the given URL.>.

My question: an analog of this method are exist of WKWebView?
If yes please show me this method, or perhaps how to use it.